# How to jitter the values only in positive range

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```r
set.seed(1)
jitter(rep(0, 7))
#> [1] -0.009379653 -0.005115044  0.002914135  0.016328312 -0.011932723
#> [6]  0.015935587  0.017787011
```

Notice that the function jitter add negative values. How can I 
parameterize the function so that it will return only positive values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a positive jitter, then perhaps you could just take the absolute value of your call:

```
x <- rep(0, 7)
abs(jitter(x))
[1] 0.009379653 0.005115044 0.002914135 0.016328312 0.011932723 0.015935587
[7] 0.017787011
```